# How to visualize multiple lanes (bus, cycle etc.) from single polyline (OSM data) in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, openstreetmap, polyline

My use case:

Single polyline is tagged with multiple lanes containing also a cycle lane.

How would I go about visualizing them side by side using Leaflet? Polyline is a set of GPS coordinates and I would like to have e.g. 3 polylines drawn where there is lane, lane, cycle lane.

I understand some kind of offsetting is required, but how do I go about calculating the offsetted GPS coordinates?

Any tips on plugins, algorithms, code examples are welcome. Since I am using Javascript, JS examples are preferred, but I can work with other languages as well.

Comment: Have you tried this yet 
[overlapping polylines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291745/displaying-overlapping-polyline-segments-as-multiple-lines-with-offsets)
looks pretty straightforward
[BusLines](http://bbecquet.github.io/Leaflet.PolylineOffset/examples/example_bus.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help, that should work. I am going to test it. I see you haven't added this as an answer, bounty could be yours otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, this sould work [Displaying overlapping polyline segments as multiple lines with offsets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291745/displaying-overlapping-polyline-segments-as-multiple-lines-with-offsets)

also an example [Bus Lines](http://bbecquet.github.io/Leaflet.PolylineOffset/examples/example_bus.html)